# No puedo conectar a servidor desde Hosting pero si desde localhost

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, server

Buenas querida comunidad redacto esta pregunta esperando que alguien tenga la respuesta, les detallo el caso:
Tengo un archivo de PHP alojado en mi cuenta de hosting, una oficina con dos proveedores de internet(al fallar uno se activa el otro), adicionalmente un servidor en la oficina con el programa DUC de no-ip para actualizar la dirección al cambiar el ISP, hasta alli todo en orden.

Con el primer proveedor de internet el archivo php hace la solicitud, recupera la información y me la muestra sin problemas, al activarse el segundo proveedor el DUC actualiza la IP destino mas sin embargo no se logra establecer de nuevo conexión, con un proveedor conecta mas no con el segundo, ahora bien si descargo el archivo php y lo ejecuto desde mi equipo personal con xamp si logra establecer conexión aun cuando esta el segundo proveedor activo. He hecho pruebas tratando de recuperar los datos en formato JSON y directo al MYSQL obteniendo siempre el mismo problema.

De forma mas resumida:

Casos proveedor 1

Script PHP en hosting---> conexion a server local = Exitosa
Script PHP en Equipo personal---> conexion a server local = Exitosa

Casos proveedor 2

Script PHP en hosting---> conexion a server local = Error
Script PHP en Equipo personal---> conexion a server local = Exitosa

Disculpen lo extenso. Muchas gracias.

EDIT:

Gracias por responder tratare de explicarme mejor, En mi cuenta de hosting y en mi maquina local tengo un archivo PHP que solicita data a un server local en oficina,  mientras en la oficina exista conexión a internet a través del primer proveedor se logra conectar , si falla este proveedor y se activa el de respaldo solo logro conectarme desde mi maquina local pero no desde el hosting:

```
    <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'AQUI LA URL');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "Prueba";
echo $result;



?>
```

Como veras tengo habilitado para mostrar errores pero no recibo ninguno.

Comment: Hola Yubel, no ha quedado claro cuál es el problema. ¿Cuáles son las pruebas que has hecho y con qué resultados? ¿Has revisado los logs de error? ¿Qué encuentras en ellos?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder añadí un poco de información al post para tratar de explicarme mejor

Comment: Los errores de `cURL` deben verificarse en base al resultado de la llamada, intenta algo así y dinos qué resultado arroja: `if($result=curl_exec($ch))
{
    var_dump($result); 
}
else
{
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
}` Pon ese bloque de verificación y quita estas tres líneas del código actual: `$result = curl_exec($ch);`, `echo "Prueba";` y `echo $result;` y pon `curl_close($ch);` al final, fuera del `if`